# Transform.up works, -transform.up after 1 second does not work well? C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If you need more context let me know. The kick timer works great on its own. I'm trying to make it so that one second after the object has been kicked into place, it will be kicked back the opposite way.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    kickTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (kickTimer > nextKick) {
        rb.AddForce (transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
        kickTimer = 0;
        nextKick = Random.Range (MinKickTime, MaxKickTime);
    }
    kickBackTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (kickBackTimer > nextKick + 1) {
        rb.AddForce (-transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
        kickTimer = 0;
        nextKick = Random.Range (MinKickTime, MaxKickTime);
    }
}
```

The result of this is that the objects kick up less than they normally would if the kick back function was not attached. The objects do kick back, but at random times, not 1 second after they kicked up. Can anybody see the problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably would like to do here is to use a queue of kick back times, which could be defined as:

```cs
Queue<float> nextKickBacks = new Queue<float>();
```

Furthermore, I would suggest not to reset the kick timer but to have a single kick/kick back time scale for ease of reference.

Finally, consider using the `Time.deltaTime` instead of `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, since it will return the proper kind of delta time automatically, as stated in the [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html).

I believe, one neat way to achieve this is the following:

```cs
void FixedUpdate()
{
  // Increase the kick timer
  kickTimer += Time.deltaTime;

  // If the next kick time has came
  if (nextKick < kickTimer) {
    // Schedule the kick back corresponding to the current kick
    nextKickBacks.Enqueue(nextKick + 1);

    // Apply the kick force
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);

    // Plan the next kick
    nextKick = kickTimer + Random.Range(MinKickTime, MaxKickTime);
  }

  // If there are more kick backs to go, and the time of the closest one has came
  if (0 < nextKickBacks.Count) {
    if (nextKickBacks.Peek() < kickTimer) {
      // Apply the kick back force
      rb.AddForce(-transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);

      // Dequeue the used kick back time
      nextKickBacks.Dequeue();
    }
  }
}
```

Please also note that this approach works even if the next kick interval is below one second (which could have been in issue with your old concept).

**UPD:** If you wish the kicks/kickbacks to occur in altering manner, please make sure the `MinKickTime` is more than 1.

Comment: Thank you this method works almost perfectly. There is more than one second delay though and I am trying to figure out why. It is about 10 seconds.

Comment: @manbearpig1 I have just noticed an error of my own (fixed in the answer): the type of the queue should indeed be float not integer. Please try changing this although I am not certain if it was what caused this delay increase.

Comment: I had already changed that so unfortunately it was not the problem. I will think about it some more hopefully I can figure it out.

Comment: @manbearpig1 Furhter, the Time.fixedDeltaTime was unneeded: consider using Time.deltaTime as it will return the proper delta time automatically, according to the documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html

Comment: I figured out how to make it run smoothly. I moved  // Plan the next kick
    nextKick = kickTimer + Random.Range(MinKickTime, MaxKickTime); to the end right before dequeue. It works perfectly now your method is great thank you.

Comment: @manbearpig1 This way, you only plan the next kick after the previous kick back completed. As far as I understand now, that was exactly what you wanted to achieve. Be careful though: this way you are apparently enqueuing an extra kickback every update and adding more and more force to the object. In order to achieve the goal I have mentioned earlier in this comment, just put the next kick planning to its previous place make sure that your MinKickTime is above 1 second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98295/discussion-between-danek-and-manbearpig1).

Answer (score 1):

When the ball is kicked into the air, the timer is reset, and nextKick is also changed, therefore by the time nextKick+1 occurs, you have already changed the value of nextKick to a random value. I think what you want is to have `nextKick = Random.Range (MinKickTime, MaxKickTime);` occur only after the second if statement/after the kickback occurs.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    kickTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (kickTimer > nextKick) {
        rb.AddForce (transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
        kickTimer = 0;
    }
    kickBackTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (kickBackTimer > nextKick + 1) {
        rb.AddForce (-transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
        kickTimer = 0;
        nextKick = Random.Range (MinKickTime, MaxKickTime);
    }
}
```

you could also just use one timer

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    kickTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (kickTimer > nextKick) {
        rb.AddForce (transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
    if (kickTimer > nextKick + 1) {
        rb.AddForce (-transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
        kickTimer = 0;
        nextKick = Random.Range (MinKickTime, MaxKickTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Curiously, no kickback happens at all in these scenarios. I thought for sure you had found the solution I was surprised to see that it didn't work.

Comment: Huh, I don't immediately see why it wouldn't kick back, try adding a debug line and check if that fires off.